# Why definition not required and synthesize required iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an interface

```
@interface A 
{
    NSMutableArray *_myArray;
} 

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

In in the implementation I have written

```
@synthesize myArray = _myArray;
```

And in the body of the code where I am using this array is only storing some arrays values which is like this...

```
-(void)updateArray:(NSArray*)p_NewValues
{
    self.myArray = nil;
    myArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]initwithArray:p_NewArray];
}
```

but unfortunate in code review I found that I don't required any variable definition only Synthesize is OK, can anybody explain why?

Comment: Even these are not required "NSMutableArray *_myArray;" and @synthesize myArray = _myArray;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/ocproperties.html)

> The @synthesize directive also synthesizes an appropriate instance
>   variable if it is not otherwise declared.

Answer (score 3):

With the modern Objective-C compiler used in the latest versions of Xcode, you don't need an explicit ivar nor do you even need the `@synthesize` anymore. Your code can now be:

```
@interface A

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;

@end

@implementation A

- (void)updateArray:(NSArray *)p_NewValues {
    self.myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:p_NewArray];
}

@end
```